# Custom Event Event Handler Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on translating a small piece of JQuery into vanilla javascript. the code here is for controlling my forms' UI.

in the debugger I am able to see that at line 36 `elem.dispatchEvent(checkValEvent)` is firing repeatedly for each run or the `.foreach` loop, however, the event handler for the "checkval" event does fire. Can't seem to find a solution.

The following is the translation(or attempted translationat least)from Jquery code.

```
var onClass = "on";
var showClass = "show";

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
   var checkValEvent = new CustomEvent("checkval");

   elem.addEventListener("changeval", function(e) {
      var label = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
      console.log(label)
      if (this.value !== "") {
         label.classList.add(showClass)
      } else {
         label.classList.remove(showClass)
      }
   })

   elem.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
      e.dispatchEvent(checkValEvent)   
   })

   elem.addEventListener("focus",function(){
      label.classList.add(onClass)   
   })

   elem.addEventListener("blur",function(){
      label.classList.remove(onClass)  
   })

   elem.dispatchEvent(checkValEvent)
});
```

Also, if it helps, Here is the Jquery it came from:

```
$(function() {
   var onClass = "on";
   var showClass = "show";

   $("input,textarea")
      .bind("checkval", function() {
         var label = $(this)
            .parent()
            .prev("label");
         if (this.value !== "") {
            label.addClass(showClass);
         } else {
            label.removeClass(showClass);
         }
      })
      .on("keyup", function() {
         $(this).trigger("checkval");
      })
      .on("focus", function() {
         $(this)
            .parent()
            .prev("label")
            .addClass(onClass);
      })
      .on("blur", function() {
         $(this)
            .parent()
            .prev("label")
            .removeClass(onClass);
      })
      .trigger("checkval");
});
```

Any possible fix you guys can think of would be greatly appreciated, 
thanks!

Comment: `checkval` != `changeval`?

Comment: Looks like a typo between the custom event name and the event being listened for.